# AWS - Seemingly random 502 errors only on some endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We are facing random 502 errors from cloudfront on different endpoints/behaviors. The endpoint is connected to a EC2 instance which have 4 cores and 16gb ram. It gives 502 randomly and the same REST call works on random restarts.
Some of the distribution settings:

Price Class: Use All Edge Locations (Best Performance)
Security Policy : TLSv1.1_2016
HTTP versions: to HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0.
Custom SSL Client Support: Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI) - (Recommended)

We have around 45 behaviors all connected to different origins or origin group.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the CloudFront documentation you'll find [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html):

> An HTTP 502 status code (Bad Gateway) indicates that CloudFront wasn't able to serve the requested object because it couldn't connect to the origin server.

There are many possible reasons for that, which depend on the kind of origin you're using. Some of them are:

- The origin server(s) are overloaded and can't respond to new requests
- There are connectivity problems somewhere in the world
- There is an issue with TLS/SSL negotiation
- DNS ([It's always DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMB6S.jpg))
- A Lambda@Edge function returns a response in the wrong format if you're using those.

If the issue is significant, i.e. more than a few random requests, you should raise a ticket with AWS support to have them look into it. It may be related to infrastructure you can't control, but I'd first check the performance metrics/monitoring/uptime of the origin servers and make sure those weren't overloaded at the time (4 cores + 16 GB RAM don't mean much without knowing the utilization).

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced random 502 errors on cloudfront, for me it was a geolocation routing policy that was in place on the target origin:

[image]

My guess is that sometimes it was hitting the DNS from a different country and thus giving the 502 error without further explanation